# How does fitEllipse work in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, shapes, ellipse

I am working with opencv and I need to understand how does the function fitEllipse exactly works. I looked at the code at (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp) and I know it uses least-squares to determine the likely ellipses. I also looked at the paper given in the documentation(Andrew W. Fitzgibbon, R.B.Fisher. A Buyer’s Guide to Conic Fitting. Proc.5th British Machine Vision Conference, Birmingham, pp. 513-522, 1995.)

But I cannot understand exactly the algorithm. For example, why does it need to solve 3 times the least square problem? why bd is initialized to 10000 before the first svd(I guess it is juste a random value for the initialization but why this value can be random?)? why does the values in Ad needs to be negative before the first svd?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Matlab code.. it might help

```
function [Q,a]=fit_ellipse_fitzgibbon(data)
  % function [Q,a]=fit_ellipse_fitzgibbon(data)
  %
  % Ellipse specific fit, according to:
  %
  %  Direct Least Square Fitting of Ellipses,
  %  A. Fitzgibbon, M. Pilu and R. Fisher. PAMI 1996
  %
  %
  % See Also:
  %   FIT_ELLIPSE_LS
  %   FIT_ELLIPSE_HALIR

  [m,n] = size(data);
  assert((m==2||m==3)&&n>5);
  x = data(1,:)';
  y = data(2,:)';

  D = [x.^2 x.*y y.^2 x y ones(size(x))];   % design matrix
  S = D'*D;                                 % scatter matrix
  C(6,6)=0; C(1,3)=-2; C(2,2)=1; C(3,1)=-2; % constraints matrix
  % solve the generalized eigensystem
  [V,D] = eig(S, C);
  % find the only negative eigenvalue
  [n_r, n_c] = find(D<0 & ~isinf(D));
  if isempty(n_c),
    warning('Error getting the ellipse parameters, will do LS');
    [Q,a] = fit_ellipse_ls(data); %
    return;
  end
  % the parameters
  a = V(:, n_c);
  [A B C D E F] = deal(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5),a(6)); % deal is slow!
  Q = [A B/2 D/2; B/2 C E/2; D/2 E/2 F];
end % fit_ellipse_fitzgibbon
```

Fitzibbon solution has some numerical stability though. See the work of Halir for a solution to this.

It is essentially least squares solution, but specifically designed so that it will produce a *valid* ellipse, not just any conic.